# Test .ovpn (open vpn) files connection in windows with python

Tags: python, docker, connection, openvpn

I have a lots of `.ovpn` files and I need to test my connection with these files to check if they are working or not and all of these connections has usernames and passwords.

I'm on windows.
Does it even work on windows or do I have to use Docker?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670358/openvpn-connection-using-python-windows/69736569#69736569) that should be close to what you are looking for.

You can use the [GUI client](https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/) too in Windows. You do not need Docker for this.

Comment: i know i can use gui client. but i need to do it automatically every day and i have lots of config files. it would be great if i could use it with loop

Comment: I see. I am not very good with Windows. You need to find a way to iterate through the .ovpn files and call each .ovpn file from the .bat file if you go with the answer I linked. Please note that I can't test the example below.
Something like:
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do  "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --command connect %%f

This thread should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script